# Get result from database/sql query

Tags: go

I have this:

```
tx, _ := db.Begin()
p := person.Person{Handle: "foo"}

rows, err := tx.Exec("INSERT INTO person (handle, email) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id", p.Handle, p.Email).
```

---

notice how it says `RETURNING id` in the sql query..how can I get the id from the first row return by the query?

I tried this:

```
var id string
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(&id, &name)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(id, name)
}
```

but I get this compile error:

> rows.Close undefined (type sql.Result has no field or method Close)

Comment: Think it should be `db.Close()` instead of `rows.Close()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Next()` on rows which get from `Exec()`. But it has `LastInsertId()` method which you can get the id.